# How to autocomplete left part of expression/equality

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I have a lot of variables in my code, and most of those like

```
    String one = new String();
    String to  = "";
```

or like

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have walked through [auto-completing-code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html)

The question is there a way to generate left part of equality marked with (empty space) into code by using hotkeys in IntelliJ IDEA?
What I want is to put cursor onto (empty space) press combination and it will generate me type and name

```
(empty space) = new String();
```

expecting to see

```
String great = new String();
```

Regards

To summarise, correct answer by [yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) works in case remove '=' from statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Introduce Variable refactoring (Ctrl-Alt-V / Cmd-Alt-V) allows you to do that.

Comment: It does not work for me, it told me "Cannot perform refactoring. Selected block should represent an expression"

Comment: Don't type in the `=` sign, the refactoring will generate it for you.

Comment: Got it, thanks, Right after I wrote new String with autocomplete, then my coursor have been inside ( and ) I pressed combination, that you said. And it works.